# Non empty list when passed to function becomes empty

Tags: c++

So I got this code. The problem is that with a for loop I create empty lists and add to them 1 integer. Then I pass the list to the DFS function and it says that the list is empty. Any ideas why this is happening?

```
#include <list>
#include<vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
list<short> integer;
vector<list<short> > all;

void DFS(list<short> ingeter, int N)
{
    if(integer.empty())
    {
        cout<<"IT IS EMPTY"<<endl;
        return;
    }
    if(integer.size() > N || (integer.size() > 0 && (integer.front() == 0 || integer.back() % 2 == 0)))
    {
        return;
    }
    cout<<"size: "<<integer.size()<<endl;
    all.push_back(integer);
    for(short i = 0; i <= 9; ++i)
    {
        integer.push_back(i);
        integer.push_front(i);
        DFS(integer, N);
        integer.pop_back();
        integer.pop_front();
    }
}
int main()
{
    int N = 8;
    for(short i = 0; i <= 9; ++i)
    {
        list<short> current;
        current.push_back(i);
        cout<<"size: "<<current.size()<<endl;
        DFS(current, N);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't just drop a bunch of code and ask us to read it. Compile a short example (http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem instead.

Comment: One `c` in SSCCEE means compilable. This code won't compile.

Comment: ok, now it is compilable

Comment: The parameter name is `ingeter` and a global variable is named `integer` - guess which one your function is accessing.

Comment: Thanks Captain! Put an answer if you wish to so I can mark it as my solution or whatever it is called the best answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are accessing the wrong variable. You named the parameter `ingeter` but your function is accessing `integer` which is a global variable.

```
void DFS(list<short> ingeter, int N)
//                   ^^^^^^^
{
    if(integer.empty())
    // ^^^^^^^
    {
    //...
    }
 }
```